# Gatling 2.0: Failed to invoke setUp method

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, gatling

I'm am having issues trying to figure out what went wrong with my 'setUp' method in the TestSimulation.scala file. It throws error *"Cannot resolve symbol setUp"* From Intellij 13.1.5, it shows that I have 2 types of 'Declarations' to choose from the Simulation.class file as shown below. Selecting either one doesn't seem to solve the issue. Please assist.

Simulation.class:

```
    package io.gatling.core.scenario
    abstract class Simulation() extends scala.AnyRef {
     ....
    def setUp(scenarios : io.gatling.core.structure.PopulatedScenarioBuilder*) : Simulation.this.SetUp = { /* compiled code */ }

class SetUp() extends scala.AnyRef {
    ....}
    def setUp(scenarios : scala.List[io.gatling.core.structure.PopulatedScenarioBuilder]) : Simulation.this.SetUp = { /* compiled code */ }
    }
```

TestSimulation.scala:

```
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import sim_replacement.SimReplacement
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class TestSimulation extends Simulation {

  val httpProtocol = http
    .baseURL("http://xx.xx.x.xx")
    .inferHtmlResources(BlackList(""".*\.css""", """.*\.js""", """.*\.ico"""), WhiteList())
    .acceptHeader("""*/*""")
    .acceptEncodingHeader("""gzip,deflate,sdch""")
    .acceptLanguageHeader("""en-US,en;q=0.8""")
    .contentTypeHeader("""application/x-www-form-urlencoded""")
    .userAgentHeader("""Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.104 Safari/537.36""")

  setUp(
    SimReplacement.scn
      .inject(rampRate(5 usersPerSec) to (100 usersPerSec) during (5 minutes))
      .protocolConfig(httpProtocol)
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your project targets the proper Scala version (2.10 for Gatling 2.0, 2.11 for master/upcoming 2.1)?

Comment: My scala-library consist of the following classes & sources:
scala-2.10.2\src\scala-actors-src.jar
scala-2.10.2\src\scala-library-src.jar
scala-2.10.2\src\scala-swing-src.jar

Comment: Are you sure your module has the Scala facet?